# How to display two C3 charts in the same row in two different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, c3.js

I've some problems with c3 plugins.
I'm trying to put 2 charts in a structure like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div id="chart2"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My output is the attached one, and i couldn't find the reason why the charts go out of the div.

[image: click here to view output]

I've already tried to use `chart.resize()` but it doesn't work (maybe i put it in the wrong place).
Can you help me ?

You can find my code here: 
[js1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF0By.png), [js2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEjhi.png), [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AAvO.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading the charts (I think!) within a div that is not displayed when the page loads, the C3 doesn't know how to size the charts correctly.
Instead of loading every chart in the Document Ready, wrap your posts in a function like this:

```
function loadStatArticoliCharts() {
    $.post(
        '{{ url('myGetter') }}/{{ data.listId }}',
        {},
        function(data) {
            grafico_fatturato = c3.generate({
                bindto: "#fatturato-mensile-barre",
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        [new Date().getFullYear() - 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        [new Date().getFullYear(), 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    ],
                    type : 'bar',
                    colors: data.colors
                },
                bar: {
                    width: 30
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category',
                        categories: months
                    },
                    y: {
                        tick: {
                            format: function(value) { return value.formatMoney(2, ',', '.') }
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    format: {
                        value: function(value) { return "€ " + value.formatMoney(2, ",", "."); }
                    }
                },
                transition: {
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                grafico_fatturato.load({
                    columns: [
                        data.columns.current,
                        data.columns.past
                    ],
                });
                grafico_fatturato.resize();
            }, 500);
        }
    );
}
```

Create a global boolean variable to store if you've already loaded the charts (so you won't trigger the load multiple times) with

```
let loadedChart1 = false;
let loadedChart2 = false;
```

Finally create a controller that will trigger the load function when you click the tab:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (ev) {
    let tabId = $(ev.target).attr("aria-controls");
    switch (tabId) {
        case "chart1":
            if (!loadedChart1) {
                loadChart1();
                loadedChart1 = true;
            }
            break;
        case "chart2":
            if (!loadedChart2) {
                loadChart2();
                loadedChart2 = true;
            }
            break;
    }
    let oldTabId = $(ev.relatedTarget).attr("aria-controls");
    $('#' + oldTabId).removeClass("active");
}
```